# Docker + vscode: wrong user and group ownership to git files

Tags: docker, github

I am just discovering all docker possibilities, being quite new to all dev-op possibilities, so please go easy on me ;-)!
I was instructed to mount and use a docker image through vscode (using docker and remote-ssh extensions) to push/pull changes from a project called, hereafter "project" with a user whose username is in the container "vscode".
The problem is the permissions seems not to be set properly when building the image.
When pulling/pushing some modifications inside the image, I got the following error:

```
vscode@3910551790a9:/workspaces/project$ git pull
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

When listing permissions in the .git folder, inside the image, I got the following:

```
vscode@3910551790a9:/workspaces/project$ ls -lart .git
total 88
-rw-rw-r--  1 super_project super_project    73 Apr 17 14:53 description
drwxrwxr-x  2 super_project super_project  4096 Apr 17 14:53 branches
drwxrwxr-x  2 super_project super_project  4096 Apr 17 14:53 info
drwxrwxr-x  5 super_project super_project  4096 Apr 17 14:53 refs
-rw-rw-r--  1 super_project super_project   257 Apr 17 14:53 packed-refs
drwxrwxr-x  3 super_project super_project  4096 Apr 17 14:53 logs
drwxr-xr-x  4 super_project super_project  4096 Apr 17 14:53 lfs
drwxrwxr-x  2 super_project super_project  4096 Apr 17 14:53 hooks
-rw-rw-r--  1 super_project super_project   337 Apr 20 09:34 config
-rw-rw-r--  1 super_project super_project   309 Apr 20 10:46 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-rw-r--  1 super_project super_project    41 Apr 20 10:46 ORIG_HEAD
drwxrwxr-x  7 super_project super_project  4096 Apr 20 12:28 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 super_project super_project    29 Apr 20 12:29 HEAD
drwxrwxr-x 37 super_project super_project  4096 Apr 20 13:55 objects
-rw-rw-r--  1 super_project super_project 24533 Apr 20 13:55 index
-rw-rw-r--  1 super_project super_project    35 Apr 20 13:55 COMMIT_EDITMSG
drwxrwxr-x  9 super_project super_project  4096 Apr 20 13:55 .
```

**Files are own by *"super_project"* whereas they are supposed to be owned by user *"vscode"*.**

Here is the relevant part of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM super_project/super_project:latest

USER root


ARG USERNAME=vscode
ARG USER_UID=1001
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID



RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils dialog 2>&1 \
    some install ...
    # Create a non-root user to use if preferred - see https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root-user.\
    && groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd -s /bin/bash --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    # [Optional] Add sudo support for the non-root user
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME\
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    # add github ssh key
    && mkdir ~vscode/.ssh/ \
    && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~vscode/.ssh/known_hosts \
    && chown -R vscode.$USER_GID ~vscode/.ssh \
    #
    # Clean up
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I do point out that everything is working fine under MacOx which is used by my boss.
I personally use ubuntu 18.04 with docker version 19.03 and vscode 1.44.
I read that there are some subtle differences in the way permissions are handle in the two systems, which may explain my issue.

Could anybody explain to me what is going on here and how to solve this permissions problem?

Thanks in advance!